# Main() thread id is different after creating another thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I've been reading and learning about POSIX threads, and tried to write some simple codes to understand it better.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* standard I/O routines */
#include <pthread.h> /* pthread functions and data structures */

/* function to be executed by the new thread */
void* PrintHello(void* data)
{
    pthread_t tid = (pthread_t)data;
    printf("Hello from new thread  %d - got %d\n", pthread_self(), tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL); /* terminate the thread */
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rc; /* return value */
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int  tid;   

    thread_id = pthread_self();
    printf("FLAG = %d ", thread_id);

    /* create a new thread that will execute 'PrintHello' */
    rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, PrintHello, (void*)thread_id);
    if(rc) /* could not create thread */
    {
        printf("\n ERROR: return code from pthread_create is %u \n", rc);
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n   Created new thread (%d) ... \n",  thread_id);
    pthread_exit(NULL); /* terminate the thread */
}
```

For this code I get the following output:

```
FLAG = 363480832 
   Created new thread (355198720) ... 
Hello from new thread  355198720 - got 363480832
```

What is bothering me is why `thread_id` which is `363480832`, becomes `355198720`, same as `thread_id` of a function that was called from `main` (`PrintHello()`). I assumed that thread id doesn't change throughout the program execution. Or is it something inside the function that changes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing anything with a `pthread_t` other than passing it to a function that takes one, you're doing something wrong. Only the pthreads API knows how to use a `pthread_t` correctly. They can have any internal structure that's convenient for the implementation.

Being a C language construct, `pthread_t` behaves more like `char *`. The necessary language constructs to make it behave like `std::string` don't exist. So you have to treat it like `char *`.

A `char *` contains a string somehow, but you have to understand its implementation to get that value out. Consider:

```
char *j = "hello";
char *k = strdup (j);
if (j == k)
   printf ("This won't happen\n");
printf ("%d\n", j);
printf ("%d\n", k); // these won't be equal
```

You can't compare `char *`'s with `==` to see if they refer to the same string. And if you print out `j` and `k`, you'll get different values.

Similarly, a `pthread_t` refers to one particular thread somehow. But you have to understand how to get the value out. Two `pthread_t`s can have different apparent values but still refer to the same thread just as two `char *`s can have different apparent values but still refer to the same string.

Just as you compare two `char *`'s with `strcmp` if you want to tell if they refer to the same string value, you compare two `pthread_t`s with `pthread_equal` to tell if they refer to the same thread.

So this line of code makes no sense:

```
printf("FLAG = %d ", thread_id);
```

A `pthread_t` is not an integer and you can't print it with a `%d` format specifier. POSIX has no printable thread IDs. If you want one, you need to code one (perhaps using `pthread_getspecific`).

Comment: Then what are these values: 355198720, 363480832, if not id's? What do they refer to?

Comment: While this is true, it's not OP's problem.

Comment: @kulan It's the same thing as my example where you print `char *`'s through `%d`. They're meaningless unless you understand the details of how `pthread_t` is implemented on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

In C, arguments are passed by value. In particular, the argument `(void *)thread_id` is an expression that's evaluated before calling `pthread_create`, so the fact that `pthread_create` writes to `thread_id` as a result of `&thread_id` being passed as the first argument is irrelevant. If you were instead passing `&thread_id` rather than `(void *)thread_id` as the argument to the new thread start function, and dereferencing it there, then you *may* see the effects you want; however, it's not clear to me that `pthread_create`'s writing of the new thread id via its first argument is required to take place before the new thread starts, so there is probably a data race if you do it that way.

Further, note that David's answer is also correct. It's invalid to print thread ids this way since they are formally an opaque type.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, PrintHello, (void*)thread_id);
```

as the manual says, `pthread_create()` shall store the ID of the created thread in the location referenced by `thread_id`. In this example, it would be modified to `355198720`, which is the tid of new thread `PrintHello()`.

Besides, it may be better to change the argument for `PrintHello` to:

```
rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, PrintHello, (void*)&thread_id);
```

and in `PrintHello()`, it would be:

```
void* PrintHello(void* data)
{
    pthread_t tid = (pthread_t)(*data);
    ...
}
```